# count unicode character using jquery

Tags: jquery, unicode, sms

I want to modify this jquery script to count unicode character also (70 for first sms, 63 for the second one (concatenated) :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    part1Count = 160;
    part2Count = 145;
    part3Count = 152;

    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
            messages = 0;
            remaining = 0;
            total = 0;
        if (chars <= part1Count) {
            messages = 1;
            remaining = part1Count - chars;
        } else if (chars <= (part1Count + part2Count)) { 
            messages = 2;
            remaining = part1Count + part2Count - chars;
        } else if (chars > (part1Count + part2Count)) { 
            moreM = Math.ceil((chars - part1Count - part2Count) / part3Count) ;
            remaining = part1Count + part2Count + (moreM * part3Count) - chars;
            messages = 2 + moreM;
        }
        $('#remaining').text(remaining);
        $('#messages').text(messages);
        $('#total').text(chars);
        if (remaining > 1) $('.cplural').show();
            else $('.cplural').hide();
        if (messages > 1) $('.mplural').show();
            else $('.mplural').hide();
        if (chars > 1) $('.tplural').show();
            else $('.tplural').hide();
    });
    $('#message').keyup();
});
</script>

<textarea name="message" value="" id="message"></textarea>
<div>
    <div><span id="remaining">160</span>&nbsp;Character<span class="cplural">s</span> Remaining</div>
    <div>Total&nbsp;<span id="messages">1</span>&nbsp;Message<span class="mplural">s</span>&nbsp;<span id="total">0</span>&nbsp;Character<span class="tplural">s</span></div>
</div>
```

source : http://www.mindrestingplace.com/2012/07/18/sms-character-counter/

Comment: How to modify this jquery script to count unicode character also?

Comment: Do you mean how to modify it to count a non-BMP character as one character (it now counts as two), or do you mean how to count one character as many due to the transmission techniques of SMS?

Comment: am developing sms script and want to count unicode character for every 70 character to be considered as 1 sms